# fading creating too much space between elements

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to display all 36 possible results when you throw a pair of dice. I use:

```
    \begin{flalign*}
    \Omega = \{&(1,1),&(1,2),&(1,3),&(1,4),&(1,5),&(1,6),&&\\
    &(2,1),&(2,2),&(2,3),&(2,4),&(2,5),&(2,6),&&\\
    &(3,1),&(3,2),&(3,3),&(3,4),&(3,5),&(3,6),&&\\
    &(4,1),&(4,2),&(4,3),&(4,4),&(4,5),&(4,6),&&\\
    &(5,1),&(5,2),&(5,3),&(5,4),&(5,5),&(5,6),&&\\
    &(6,1),&(6,2),&(6,3),&(6,4),&(6,5),&(6,6),&&\\
    \end{flalign*}
```

Unfortunately, I see far too much space between some elements, see picture.
Would you be so kind to explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

[image]

[image: too much space between falling elements]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why do you place these many `&` anyways? The numbers would be aligned nicely even without (except for the first one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `flalign` and all other `align`-like environments work. They form groups of two columns, in which cells are right and left aligned, and then add spaces between groups. You are probably looking for `array`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
    \setlength\arraycolsep{\smallskipamount}
    \begin{array}{r @{\,} *6{l}}
        \Omega = \{&(1,1),&(1,2),&(1,3),&(1,4),&(1,5),&(1,6),\\
                   &(2,1),&(2,2),&(2,3),&(2,4),&(2,5),&(2,6),\\
                   &(3,1),&(3,2),&(3,3),&(3,4),&(3,5),&(3,6),\\
                   &(4,1),&(4,2),&(4,3),&(4,4),&(4,5),&(4,6),\\
                   &(5,1),&(5,2),&(5,3),&(5,4),&(5,5),&(5,6),\\
                   &(6,1),&(6,2),&(6,3),&(6,4),&(6,5),&(6,6)\,\}
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The line `\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}` decreases distance between columns to `4pt`. By default, `arraycolsep` is set to `5pt`. This distance is added on each side of each separator. Hence, the overall distance between columns is doubled and equal to `10pt` by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!